# Adding Matrices Code in C HELP! I don't know what's wrong

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, runtime-error

The assignment asks us to finish a code that adds matrices up and I'm not too sure what I'm supposed to be returning. It tells me that there's a runtime error
but I don't know how to fix it. It will be due pretty soon so someone please help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int** getMatrix(int n, int m);
int** allocateMatrix(int n, int m);
int** addMatrices(int** A, int** B, int n, int m);
void printMatrix(int** A, int n, int m);
void deallocateMatrix(int** A, int n);


// This program reads in two n by m matrices A and B and
// prints their sum C = A + B
//
// This function is complete, you do not need to modify it
// for your homework
int main() {
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    assert(n > 0 && m > 0);
    printf("Enter matrix A:\n");
    int** A = getMatrix(n, m);
    printf("Enter matrix B:\n");
    int** B = getMatrix(n, m);
    int** C = addMatrices(A, B, n, m);
    printf("A + B = \n");
    printMatrix(C, n, m);
    deallocateMatrix(A, n);
    deallocateMatrix(B, n);
    deallocateMatrix(C, n);
}

// Creates a new n by m matrix whose elements are read from stdin
//
// This function is complete, you do not need to modify it
// for your homework
int** getMatrix(int n, int m) {
int** M = allocateMatrix(n, m);
int i, j;

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Input row %d elements, separated by spaces: ", i);
    for ( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
    }
}
return M;
}

// Allocates space for an n by m matrix of ints
// and returns the result
int** allocateMatrix(int n, int m) {
// Homework TODO: Implement this function
int i, j;
int** L;

L = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        L[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
    }
}
}

// Adds two matrices together and returns the result
int** addMatrices(int** A, int** B, int n, int m) {
// Homework TODO: Implement this function
int j, i;
int** C;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
    }
}

}

// Prints out the entries of the matrix
void printMatrix(int** A, int n, int m) {
// Homework TODO: Implement this function
int i, j;
int** C;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0 ; j < m; j++) {
     printf("%d\t", C[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  }
}

// Deallocates space used by the matrix
void deallocateMatrix(int** A, int n) {
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problems but please [read this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) about casting the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Alright, I will. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- In `allocateMatrix` you allocate space for `n` *integers*, not *pointers* to integers.
- In many function you use an uninitialized pointer `C`.
- In many function declared to return something, you don't return anything at all.

These things, and probably others, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I just recently learned how to allocate spaces, I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do/use malloc. Also aren't I initializing them with "int** C;"?

Comment: Should I return like: "return C**;"? and "return L**;"?

Comment: @Sara A pointer must point somewhere for it to be valid. You must initialize it, or assign to it. And yes you should do e.g. `return L;` in your `allocateMatrix` function.

Comment: Where would I point it to and how do I do that?    int **C;? I'm sorry for so many questions. I'm not that good at this :/

Comment: I know that pointers point to things but I don't know when to use them and why we would need anything to point to anything.

Comment: @Sara Allocate memory for `C` as well, just like you did for `A` and `B`

Comment: Now my code is running but it's giving me only 0's. I added in int** C = allocateMatrix(n, m); to all the int** C I had, is the problem in my addMatrices? @CoolGuy

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on [@Someprogrammerdude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)['s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42382803/3049655)

- You should be allocating room for `n` integer pointers (`int*`s) and then in each row, allocate memory for `m` integers (`int`s). So, use

  ```
  // Allocates space for an n by m matrix of ints
  // and returns the result
  int** allocateMatrix(int n, int m) {
      int i, j;
      int** L;

      L = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);       /* Make `n` rows */
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {            /* For each row, */
          L[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m); /* Make room for `m` ints */
      }

      return L; /* Return the allocated variable. See 3rd point ↓ */
  }
  ```

  I've removed the casts because [they aren't recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). I leave error checking `malloc` upto you.
- You use `C` uninitialized: `int** C;`. Allocate memory for it just as you did for `A` and `B`:

  ```
  int** C = allocateMatrix(n, m);
  ```
- You forgot to return variables from functions. Add `return L;` and `return C;` at the end of the functions `allocateMatrix` and `addMatrices` respectively.